When applying for a PhD or research related jobs, should a LinkedIn profile be a copy of the CV?
I am interested in applying to a PhD in epidemiology in the US and jobs related to public health research (also in the US). I already have my CV, should my LinkedIn profile be a copy of my CV or how should I differentiate it from my CV?
Does the same apply to public health jobs outside of the US like in Europe?

No one in academia cares about LinkedIn^.
If you're applying to PhD programs, they'll have a structured application process with specific application materials. The admissions committee will be very busy, they're not going to go digging for other material that is not part of the application, the applications are probably already longer than they'd prefer for the number of applicants they review.
Exceptions might occasionally apply for social media content that would indicate you're a bad fit for a program.
^Okay, I'm sure you'll find someone, this is hyperbole but I think instructive hyperbole

This may be true for the US, but not necessarily elsewhere (the question is about the USA, so this is fine). I just wanted to mention that I have seen situations where you were glad to get at least one good application for an advertised PhD position, and maybe five in total.

@Bryan Krause, thanks for the insight! I will definitely keep this in mind with my applications.

Your LinkedIn profile should contain your CV and expand on the content of your CV. But don't expect that any content in it is seen in your application.
Your question is primarily about PhD programs but does also address the job hunt. I can speak with experience primarily on the latter. Across my brief time in academia and my longer industry experience, I have seemed to be the one lone person (in my circles) looking for additional online information about candidates. I don't do this for all candidates. But when we reach the point of having weeded out 90% in a large pool and we need to get down to the last 5%, that's when I'm looking for more information.
To me, if I can find good additional information about the candidate through LinkedIn or other major domain-specific sites (GitHub in computer programming), I use that and point it out to my colleagues reviewing the applications. So, just in case you run into someone like me, I recommend having your LinkedIn profile current with your best foot forward. If you have something to show your quality that can't quite fit into a CV, put it there. I love it when candidates have something that really demonstrates their work that I can go find. When I do, that is a differentiator.
But, overall, don't expect someone like me to be a decision maker in your academic or industry applications. I haven't met anyone else who does this.

I've done it as a technical interviewer for IT jobs, but most people don't have their LinkedIn profile as up-to-date as the resume they just submitted, and what I want to know about a candidate I usually can't learn outside of an interview. So I agree it's not very common for people to check LinkedIn and one reason may be the limited usefulness of what's there.

@Dana, thanks for the insight! I will also keep this in mind with my profile.

Personally, I would expect that the CV you submit with a job application is tailored to the role in question, whereas anything you put on LinkedIn is more generic. I would expect a candidate to supply information on a CV that is a bit more "in confidence" than anything they publish for the world to see.
